# Google-cloud-recommendations How Can I recognize UserEvent was deleted or not?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-recommendation

I executed delete UserEvents operation by using Google Recommendation AI API [userEvents:purge](https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.catalogs.userEvents/purge).

But I cannot know whether method was success and UserEvents was deleted or not.

API response shows me only Operation name. I used [operations.get](https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.operations/get) to refer the Operation detail. But, it returns also operation name only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [list of user event](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/manage-user-events#listing_user_events) (You use a [filter string](https://cloud.google.com/recommendations-ai/docs/manage-user-events#filter) to specify which user events you want returned).
This example lists user events with a type of `purchase-complete` for a specific time period that are missing corresponding catalog items:

```
curl -X GET
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"" \
    "https://recommendationengine.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/eventStores/default_event_store/userEvents?filter=eventType%3Dpurchase-complete%20eventTime%20%3E%20%222018-04-23T18%3A25%3A43.511Z%22%20eventTime%20%3C%20%222019-02-12T18%3A30%3A43.511Z%22%20eventsMissingCatalogItems"
```

The decoded filter string looks like this:

```
filter=
    eventType=purchase-complete
    eventTime > "2018-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"
    eventTime < "2019-02-12T18:30:43.511Z"
    eventsMissingCatalogItems
```